# Java, a method to pin and align an array

Tags: java, arrays, bytebuffer, memory-alignment

Can I create an integer array with specific alignment and stop gc from moving it?

```
 int [] arr = stopGcAndPageAlign(new int[1024]);
 or
 int [] arr = pin(align(new int[1024],4096));
```

so I can use it as a source of an opencl program using USE_HOST_PTR(this needs page alignment or some big number like 4096-alignment)

When I crreate an array 4M elements long, it has high probabilty of having good alignment but when array is shorter, it doest get aligned and opencl fails.

I need a method to get a simple java array then make it pinned and aligned (as in direct byte buffer) without going into JNI. Should I wrap direct byte buffer as an unmanaged java array instead? (But this would be harder maybe?)

In C#, there is marshal option, maybe java has something similar?

Can I tell GC to stop managing it and move to some empty/aligned location for me?

Could below code work always?:

```
  // can java move the second array right at ending of first one or starting of next page?
  public class MyAlignedArrayWrapper
  {
       public int [] alignerArray;
       public int [] alignedArray;
       public MyAlignedArrayWrapper()
       {
              alignerArray=new int[1024*1024*32]; // forces below alignment
              alignedArray=new int[113];          // so this is page aligned
                                                  // at least
       }

       public int[] getArray()
       {
             return alignedArray;
       }
  }
```

I think some java guys desperately waiting for this to add even more speed to their applications but without having forced to consume more memory than padding needed.

Comment: I would not expect this to be possible without JNI.  Normal Java objects are always eligible to be moved by the GC.

Comment: Can I tell GC to stop it and move an array for me?

Comment: Nope. You pretty much have no control over the gc as long as you stay in javaland

Comment: The GC is a magical black box.  You have no control over it; it can move any object at any time for any reason.

Comment: Then only easy option is creating a direct byte buffer and use position(p) on it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect position(p) to do.

Comment: It moves backing array to that position maybe?

Comment: ...no, it doesn't move the backing array at all.  It's just that `ByteBuffer` has an index where reading and writing is done from, from 0 to its length.  Even direct byte buffers don't expose any way to look at or control their position in memory.

Comment: Have you looked at sun.misc.Unsafe.allocateMemory()? http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/misc/Unsafe.java.html

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I think I can use that if I cn get address of pointer and after some wrapping with some destructors to auto delete when java exits.

Comment: But it will be removed in java 9 ?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik, yes, I believe so.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik No, it's had a reprieve: http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/260

Comment: IMHO the only semi-pure way to achieve that is to use a direct `ByteBuffer`. The `Unsafe.allocateMemory()` + other `Unsafe` methods to access this memory is unjustified. By the way [this article](http://psy-lob-saw.blogspot.cz/2013/01/direct-memory-alignment-in-java.html) is quite insteresting, especially the part about `ByteBuffer` alignment.

Comment: What about an object with additional array before the orgiinal array to make it aligned automagically by java? Edited the question, could you look at it please?